# Printing a binary tree in the specific format

Tags: python, binary-tree

```
def str_tree(atree,indent_char ='.',indent_delta=2):
    def str_tree_1(indent,atree):
        if atree == None:
            return ''
        else:
            answer = ''
            answer += str_tree_1(indent+indent_delta,atree.right)
            answer += indent*indent_char+str(atree.value)+'\n'
            answer += str_tree_1(indent+indent_delta,atree.left)
            return answer
    return str_tree_1(0,atree) 

def build_balanced_bst(l):
    d = []
    if len(l) == 0:
        return None

    else:
        mid = (len(l)-1)//2
        if mid >= 1:
            d.append(build_balanced_bst(l[:mid]))
            d.append(build_balanced_bst(l[mid:]))
        else:
            return d
```

The build_balanced_bst(l) takes in a list of unique values that are sorted in increasing order. It returns a reference to the root of a well-balanced binary search tree. For example, calling build_ballanced_bst( list(irange(1,10)) returns a binary search tree of height 3 that would print as:

```
......10
....9
..8
......7
....6
5
......4
....3
..2
....1
```

The str_tree function prints what the build_balanced_bst function returns

I am working on the build_balanced_bst(l) function to make it apply to the str_tree function. I used the middle value in the list as the root’s value. 
But when I call the function as the way below:

```
l = list(irange(1,10))
t = build_balanced_bst(l)
print('Tree is\n',str_tree(t),sep='')
```

it doesn't print anything. Can someone help me to fix my build_balanced_bst(l) function?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the `str_tree` method as it is, here's the remaining code.

```
class Node:
    """Represents a single node in the tree"""
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def build_balanced_bst(lt):
    """
    Find the middle element in the sorted list
    and make it root.
    Do same for left half and right half recursively.
    """

    if len(lt) == 1:
        return Node(lt[0])
    if len(lt) == 0:
        return None

    mid = (len(lt)-1)//2
    left = build_balanced_bst(lt[:mid])
    right = build_balanced_bst(lt[mid+1:])
    root = Node(lt[mid], left, right)
    return root


ordered_list = list(range(1,11))
bst=build_balanced_bst(ordered_list)
bst_repr = str_tree(bst)
print(bst_repr)
```

The output comes out as follows:

```
......10
....9
..8
......7
....6
5
......4
....3
..2
....1
```